# Bold text doesn't work unless it stands on its own

Tags: bug, markdown

Here's bold text on its own:

> **strong text**

Here's bold text *not* on its own:

> **strong text** **strong text**

Can we fix this?

Comment: For the record, looks like 2 spaces between the bolded phrases in your second scenerio works correctly, and also bold & italics works as intended (i.e. **strong text** ***strong text***).

Comment: And since I'm sure someone will claim this is not a duplicate - the last paragraph of Tim Stone's answer covers this perfectly: *"...the strict bold-italic parser needs a space (or other non-word character) to match, and the first bold italic group gobbles the single space you had there originally, depriving the [second] bold group of it."*

Comment: @animuson but why though?